# Delete and DeleteAll action override in yii2 ActiveController

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

Hi everyone i am implementing restful api in `yii2` and having a conflict in `ActionDelete` and `ActionDeleteall`

when i pass one parameter in url like `http://localhost/yii2-api/api/modules/v1/countries/CD` it works fine and deletes the record `CD` from database with `DELETE` request. I dont know how can i pass multiple `codes` in url so that it redirects to `actionDeleteall`. Here is my `controller` code.

```
class CountryController extends ActiveController
{
public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Country';

public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions();
    unset($actions['index']);
    unset($actions['create']);
    unset($actions['delete']);
    unset($actions['update']);
    unset($actions['view']);
    return $actions;
}

public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $model=$this->findModel($id);

    if($model->delete())
    {
        $this->setHeader(200);
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'data'=>array_filter($model->attributes)),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    }
    else
    {

        $this->setHeader(400);
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>0,'error_code'=>400,'errors'=>$model->errors),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

}

public function actionDeleteall()
{
    $ids=json_decode($_REQUEST['codes']);

    $data=array();

    foreach($ids as $id)
    {
        $model=$this->findModel($id);

        if($model->delete())
            $data[]=array_filter($model->attributes);
        else
        {
            $this->setHeader(400);
            echo json_encode(array('status'=>0,'error_code'=>400,'errors'=>$model->errors),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            return;
        }
    }

    $this->setHeader(200);
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'data'=>$data),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

}

}
```

Here is my `urlmanager` code

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => 'v1/country',   // our country api rule,
                'tokens' => [
                    '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
                ],
            ]
        ],
    ]
```

Let me know how can i override that action and access it with multiple `codes` passed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could post an array of id values   array and perform a loop

This is just a brief suggestion
obviuosly you should eval a proper error an resulting echo management

```
  public function actionDelete($myArray)
  {
      foreach( $myArray as $key => $value){

        $model=$this->findModel($value)
        $model->delete();
      } 
}
```

If you have you array of id in

```
 $myArray[0] = 'CD';
 $myArray[1] = 'AA';
```

the url should be

http://localhost/yii2-api/api/horsebuzz/api/web/v1/countries/myArray=[27,28]

Or if you use code use actionDelete($code) ... ad so on

Or better if use UrlHelper

```
  Url::to(['/countries/delete' , 'myArray' => [27,28] ]); 

  Url::to(['/countries/delete' , 'myArray' => $myArray ]);
```

Comment: tried that as well but it goes to `actionDelete($id)` only if i pass 1 value in url like http://localhost/yii2-api/api/web/v1/countries/27 and if i pass http://localhost/yii2-api/api/web/v1/countries/codes=[27,28] with method `DELETE` it gives error of 404.

Comment: still getting 404 error if i pass `countries/ids=[27,28]` only works if i pass `countries/27`

Comment: Try var_dump the array you receive in actionDelete and eventually update your question with the result

Comment: Actually it is not going in to `ActionDelete($ids)` method when i pass array in url and thats the problem. It only goes into `ActionDelete` if i pass 1 value only like `countries/27` with delete method in postman.

Comment: No ActionDelete($id)  but actionDelete($myArray) or the same name you use in Url::to(['/countries' , 'myArray' => $myArray ]);  the name of param in url::to and the name of var is function Param must match .

Comment: yeah i mean it does match. `actionDelete($ids)` and i pass url like `countries/ids=[27,28]` right.but it can not find the action when i pass array.

Comment: query strings are passed like this `controller/action?param_name=param_value`. note the **`?`** there

Comment: @leninhasda  the use of  ? or not for passing the param is related to the configuration of urlManager  (prettyUrl don't use ?) for this the UrlHelper revolve the proper url depending of the urlManager configuration

Comment: i might be wrong, but i have seen prettyUrl uses `?` in at least 2 scenario (1) when controller name is more than one word (ex: `about-us/update?id=10`) (2) and when passing more than one query params (ex: `?id=10&enabled=true`).

Comment: if you assign the url typing inside the browser navigation bar you must form a proper url ... but using UrlHelper is the Url:to() function that (using the param ) build the proper url...is for this is suggest (ever) the use of UrlHelper .. Url::to() in this case you are not dependent of the urlmanager configuration ..

Answer (score 1):

first disable strict parsing in urlmanager

```
'enableStrictParsing' => false
```

then you can call your custom actions with any method
the url will look like

```
http://localhost/yii2-api/api/web/v1/country/uraction
```

Comment: yeah i tried that too.It still works like before and if i pass country/deleteall it doesnt work at all and throws 404 error.

Comment: @MikeRoss any extra configs in .htaccess?